# PHP table for output data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask about output a table in php after looping some data. Previously, I always do loop data to table just horizontally or vertically. But right now, I want to put this looping data to a table horizontally and vertically, so the result could be like this:

```
data1 | data2 | data3 | data4

data5 | data6 | data7 | data8
```

and still like that until looping over. So i get 1 data from my table and put it on like that.

My code right now is:

```
<?php 
require ('server.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ekskul");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
    echo "No data.";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    while ($roweks = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<tr class="dark">';
        echo "<td>$roweks[nama]</td>";
        if ($i % 4 == 0) {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $i += 1;
    }
}
?>
```

I don't get logic about throw the result horizontally, because what I get is always vertically:

```
data1

data2

data3

...

datan
```

Comment: mysql_* function are deprecated ,... form php 5.5 so it will be problem ... instead use pdo or mysqli

Comment: you are closing the tr but not opening  the other row

Comment: @raheelshan looks like opening .. `echo '<tr class="dark">';`

Comment: yes because you are spitting rows not columns and complaining that your code is producing rows. Take a look at my answer

Comment: @NullPointer No problem in my php.. it just showed up only horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  tr opening before the while loop if condition occurs then close the tr and open new tr ..

```
<?php
    require ('server.php');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ekskul");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
        echo "No data.";
    } else {
        $i = 1;
        echo "<table>";
        echo '<tr class="dark">';
        while ($roweks = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo "<td>".$roweks['nama']."</td>";
            if ($i % 4 == 0) {

                echo "</tr>";
                echo '<tr class="dark">';
            }
            $i += 1;
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

how bout this

```
<?php 
require ('server.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ekskul");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
    echo "No data.";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    echo '<table>';
    while ($roweks = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<tr class="dark">';
                echo "<td>$roweks[nama]</td>";
            if ($i % 4 == 0) {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $i += 1;
    }
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should have been so easy.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <?
    $i = 1;
    while ($roweks = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<td>$roweks[nama]</td>";
        if ($i == 4 ) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i = 1;
        }else{
            $i += 1;
        }

    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it doesn't works well, it showed like this http://www.4freeimagehost.com/show.php?i=4d8eb150650a.jpg

Comment: Ok i have edited it try again the code of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new row every 4 items and skip the last one is the number of items is in multiple of 4.

```
<?php 
    require ('server.php');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ekskul");
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($num_row < 1) {
        echo "No data.";
    } else {
        $i = 0;
        echo '<tr class="dark">';
        while($roweks = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $i++;
            echo "<td>$roweks[nama]</td>";
            if($i % 4 == 0 && $i != $num_row)
            {
                echo "</tr>";
                echo '<tr class="dark">';
            }                   
            $i++;
        }
        if ($i % 4 != 1) {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```